# "current directory" notation not working

Tags: php, directory

I was taught that it's good practice to specify the directory of a file you're linking to, even when the file is in the current directory. So, for example, use "./constants.inc.php" as opposed to "constants.inc.php". This has generally worked fine for me, except in one particular spot in my code I get the following PHP error when I use the ./ notation:

> Warning: require(./constants.inc.php) [function.require]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\widget_corp\includes\functions.inc.php on line 4
>
> Fatal error: require() [function.require]: Failed opening required './constants.inc.php' (include_path='.;C:\xampp\php\PEAR;C:\xampp\htdocs\websites\mathverse\includes') in C:\xampp\htdocs\widget_corp\includes\functions.inc.php on line 4

Writing "./constants.inc.php" gives this error, but "constants.inc.php" doesn't (PHP seems to find the file just fine). Can someone tell me why the ./ notation doesn't work in this particular case? Perhaps it's something very simple I'm missing?

To give a bit more context (if necessary), the error is in the function below (line 2), which is in my PHP functions file (called functions.inc.php) which is inside an includes directory. The constant.inc.php file is also inside the includes directory.

Thank you.

```
function connect_to_db() {
  require("./constants.inc.php");
  $connection_id = mysql_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASS);
  if (!$connection_id) {
    die("Database connection failed: " . mysql_error());
  }
  $db_selection_was_successful = mysql_select_db(DB_NAME, $connection_id);
  if (!$db_selection_was_successful) {
    die("Database selection failed: " . mysql_error());
  }
}
```

Comment: `./somefile` is no different from `somefile`. I fail to see how this is a good practice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Writing "./constants.inc.php" gives this error, but "constants.inc.php" doesn't (PHP seems to find the file just fine). Can someone tell me why the ./ notation doesn't work in this particular case? Perhaps it's something very simple I'm missing?

The only explanation I have is that PHP seems to be finding the `constants.inc.php` file in one of the directories in the include path - most likely `C:\xampp\htdocs\websites\mathverse\includes`.

Comment: That's a really good idea, except that I checked the directories of the include path, and there's no file called constants.inc.php.

Comment: Strange. What happens when using @Genesis' method below?

Comment: I'm not familiar with genesis' method. Do I just type that in literally, or are there placeholders in there?

Comment: @Bill type it literally. It will give you the full current path relative to the *included file* rather than the main script. It would be interesting to see what happens. Also, which directory is the constants file in exactly?

Comment: Now the warning is: Warning: require(C:\xampp\htdocs\widget_corp\includes/../constants.inc.php) failed...

Comment: Oh, and the constants file and the functions file are both in the includes directory. That's why I'm not understanding why the current directory reference ./ won't work.

Comment: @Bill because relative paths are always relative to the main script in `c:\xampp\htdocs\widget_corp\`. What baffles me is that `constants.inc.php` works - it shouldn't.

Comment: Ah, that explains why /includes/constants.inc.php works. Thanks for teaching me something new there. Yes, I don't know why "constants.inc.php" works either in that case. This particular include directory is not in my include path.

Comment: @Bill then the only explanation left is that if used without `./`, it looks in both the main script's and the current file's directories. That would be new to me, but I wouldn't exclude the possibility that the behaviour has changed in one of the more recent versions of PHP

Comment: @Pekka see my newly added answer!

Answer (score 3):

even with or without `./` PHP will be searching for same file (in case of `./`, it won't search in include_path) , and this means that constats.inc.php DOES NOT exist.

Try this one

```
require(dirname(__FILE__)."/../constants.inc.php");
```

Comment: Or `__DIR__` if you're using PHP 5.3+

Comment: @richsage: I wanted to avoid this, because there are users which are talking to ALWAYS give most-compatible help

Comment: sure, I wasn't suggesting replace it entirely, just as an "optional extra" :-)

Comment: How can it not exist? I see it in front of my eyes! Plus, require("constants.inc.php") _works_.

Comment: +1 to even out because this is the ideal method, but your first claim is not correct: without `./` PHP will search in the include path; with `./`, as far as I know, it will not.

Comment: @Bill So it exists in `C:\xampp\htdocs\widget_corp\includes\`? Where does your main script run?

Comment: @Pekka: The main script is run from the parent directory of the includes file: c:\xampp\htdocs\widget_corp\

Comment: @Bill: so you'll have to include includes/constants.inc.php as far as I know, PHP isn't searching for current proccessed file. or use my method in answer

Comment: @genesis: Yes, includes/constants.inc.php works too, but I still don't see then why ./constants.inc.php doesn't work, since constants.inc.php and functions.inc.php are both in the includes directory.

Comment: @genesis, not sure where that downvote came from either - not me :-)

Comment: @Bill: but your main script is in parent directory, and thats source of your problems

Comment: @genesis, yes, you're right. You and Pekka have set me straight on that. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Create the following heirachy:

```
index.php // echo 'I am in the top directory';
folder1/
    index.php // echo 'I am in folder 1';
    folder2/
        index.php // 'echo I am in foler' 2
```

on your top level index.php require `folder1/index.php`. From that require `'folder2/index.php';`

This works no problem. However add a `./` before the `folder2/index.php` and you will get an error. It seems as once you specify which folder you want by using the `.`, it has to be relative to the current working directory. But if left open, the path will be checked in the calling scripts own directory too.

[From the manual:](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php)

> Files are included based on the file path given or, if none is given, the include_path specified. If the file isn't found in the include_path, **include will finally check in the calling script's own directory and the current working directory before failing**. The include construct will emit a warning if it cannot find a file; this is different behavior from require, which will emit a fatal error.